# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UIWebView delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got a problem - I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to set UIWebView.delegate = self;

My code:

vkLogin.h -

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface vkLogin : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *authBrowser;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *authBrowser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

vkLogin.m -

```
#import "vkLogin.h"
#import "bteamViewController.h"

@implementation vkLogin

@synthesize authBrowser;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
    activityIndicator.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    authBrowser = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    authBrowser.delegate = self;
    authBrowser.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:authBrowser];

    NSString *authLink = @"http://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=-&scope=audio&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:authLink];

    [authBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)authBrowser
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lol" message:@"OLOLO" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

}
@end
```

So, if i'm commeting delegate string - everything working fine, but I didn't recieve my webViewDidFinishLoad event.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Question aside, congrats for being the 100,000 objective-c tagged question!

Comment: Assign `authlink` this way and try again: `NSString *authLink = @"http://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=-&scope=audio&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token";`

Comment: I suggest editing your scheme and turning on zombie objects.  It's likely to provide better information about what is being incorrectly accessed.

Comment: I'm reassigned authLink but all still the same. With enabled zombies I get: 2012-09-06 18:59:46.177 vkPlayer[2302:c07] *** -[vkLogin respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x68236f0; (ps. sorry im very new to objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error isn't in the code you have posted. Your zombie message is saying your reference to `vkLogin` is bad. So you need to look at whatever class creates and holds a reference to your `vkLogin` class.

That class should be doing something like a `vkLogin *foo = [[vkLogin alloc] init];`

Update:

Based on your comments it looks like you are creating a local variable for `vkLogin`. It would be most useful to see the code creates and uses `vkLogin` and how it's called. Barring that, here are a few guesses.

You are called the method which creates and adds `vkLogin` to a subView more than once. (Each time would create a new instance).
You have some sort of call back which can occur after `vkLogin` has been removed.

My guess is `vkLogin` should be a `property` in your class, not a local method variable.

in your .h you would add
`@proprerty (strong, nonatomic) vkLogin *vk;`

and in your .m file you could refer to it as `self.vk` so you'd create it and add it as a subview like:

```
self.vk = [[vkLogin alloc] init]; 
[self.view addSubview:self.vk];
```

*On a side note, convention says we should start class names with a capital letter, so you'd name the class `VkLogin` which would make it easily distinguishable from a variable named `vkLogin` (but worry about that after you solve the problem)*

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC. And yes, like you've posted: vkLogin *vk = [[vkLogin alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubView: vk];

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot! This really helped. I got your note, now I'll start class names with a capital letter. :)